# Append new input from one form to another form without replacing existing text

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have 2 forms

One is the main form and another is a second form.

I have a text field called Text123 in the main form, and it gets its value from the second  form. The second form has a button that when I press sends the input into the text123 on the main form. However, I want to continue to add text to the text123 if data already exists in that field. but every time I press this button to send the text, it replaces it with the new one. How do I make it append the new selection with a comma.

this is the code  I have to do my thing but it just replaces the exisiting values, instead of adding the new selection.

```
Forms![copy of frmcci].ccif7.Value = Me.Text2.Value + "," + Me.Text2.Value
```

[image]

I was able to do what I was looking for with this new code:

```
    If IsNull(Forms!frmcci.c71) Then

        Forms!frmcci.c71.Value = Me.Text2.Value

        ElseIf Forms!frmcci.c71.Value <> "" Then
        Forms!frmcci.c71.Value = Forms!frmcci.c71.Value & "," & Me.Text2.Value

     End If
```

Comment: Protip: **name things**. Rename `Text2` to something meaningful. Rename `copy of frmcci` to something meaningful as well. `ccif7` isn't meaningful either. Thank yourself later. Also you should use the `&` sting-concatenation operator. Using `+` will work, until it doesn't.

Comment: Is the second form a subform within the main form (i.e. embedded within the main form) or a separate form in its own right?

Comment: For example, I'm reading your post and I have no idea whether `ccif7` is the textbox on the left, the textbox on the right, or something else entirely. Ditto for `Text2`. Also what's `Me` referring to? Are all these controls not on `[copy of frmcci]`? `CodeBox` and `CountryOfOriginBox` would have made things so much simpler.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  And you can see the image.... so, erm, my comment - guess it's fairly obvious if you can see the image. One day they'll unblock the website here. :)

Comment: Both forms are different forms. Text2 is th country of origin field in the second form seen in the image. cci7 is the name of the text field that gets the value from text2

Comment: So `cci7` is the field that needs to be "appended"? then it should be the LHS operand of the concatenation operation.

Comment: yes, cci7 is the field that gets the appended. and for example if I append one time, it appends to cci7, if I choose a new value and append again, it should append to the existing one.

Comment: Hi all I was able to do what I was asking for with a new code I generated. it works perfectly, but feel free to suggest edits if you have a better recommendation. The code is in the question